# Calling previously defined functions within other functions(Python)

Tags: python, function, object

I know this question has been asked a lot on this site, but for some reason no matter what I look at and try it's not helping my code. I'm working on an increasingly extensive combat algorithm for a small game, and in the object that defines all the functions that do the math I also want to have a function with a bunch of print statements that can be called in these other functions so I don't have a ton of the same print statements in every function.
So, a simplified version of this would be:

```
def print():
     print("stuff and things")
def combatMath():
     #math stuff happens here
     print()
     #call print to print out the results
```

The `print` function would take in arguments from the object, as well as the results of `combatMath` then print them out so you can see your current HP, EP, MP, etc.
So, basically this comes down to being able to call a function within another function, which I can't seem to figure out. A simple explanation would be appreciated. Please let me know if I need to elaborate on this.

Comment: Have you tried calling it as self::print() or whatever they python equivalent is?

Comment: What programming language is this coming from? And could you elaborate on it so I can translate into python?

Comment: In python 3 `print` is a builtin function, in python 2 it is a keyword. In both it is not recommended to use keywords or builtins as names of your functions. if you name it different, I dont see any issues with calling other functions. If you can provide more details on what is causing errors or what are your expectations, we can help you better.

Comment: I was just using those names as examples, the actual function names are `attackPrint` and `Attack`.

Comment: That's PHP, Java, etc - see my answer for Python

Comment: still holds - without `self.`, Python doesn't know where to find that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the builtin `print` instead of the one you've defined for your class.  Call that one using `self.print()`

```
class test:
    def print(self):
         print("stuff and things")
    def combatMath(self):
         #math stuff happens here
         self.print()
         #call print to print out the results
```

[edit]

Even if you're not using a builtin, Python still doesn't know where to look.  Telling it to look in the class declaration for that method directs it to where you want it to go:

```
class test:
def t1(self):
     print("stuff and things")
def t2(self):
     #math stuff happens here
     self.t1()
     #call print to print out the results
```

run with this

```
c = test()
c.t2()
```

gives the expected

```
"stuff and things"
```

as opposed to this declaration, which doesn't know where to find t1 and therefore gives a

```
NameError: global name 't1' is not defined

class test:
    def t1(self):
         print("stuff and things")
    def t2(self):
         #math stuff happens here
         t1()
         #call print to print out the results
```

Comment: The facepalm that occured when I read that. Many thanks.
Strangely, though, I ran into this problem that I've had before, where it says that I need two arguments, and three were given when I called the function, even though I only called it with two arguments. I forget if you just add an x or something extra variable to fix that?

Comment: Python adds "self" as an argument passed to every function, so you're always passing it one more parameter than you think you are.  In this case, for example, `t2` has to be declared as receiving `self` even though a call to the function is written `t2()` - with no arguments passed at all.  If it isn't declared like that, you get exceptions - actually got it just then when I was writing this example for you.